# AS3 Symbols resize relative to stage

Tags: actionscript-3, resize, symbols

I have a SWF that loads and a symbol, and I want the SWF to have the same `resize()` functions and the symbol stay in the same `y` position as if the stage `width` / `height` didn't interact.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your question is not really clear. Do you want to update the position of your symbol when your application resizes?

Answer (score 1):

If you are aiming to just avoid your display objects resizing themselves, but don't really care about the stage size difference, you could try playing with the Stage.scaleMode property: [Stage.scaleMode property](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/StageScaleMode.html)

Setting it to "NO_SCALE" will let you resize the player's stage and all the contents won't be affected size-wise. However, if you selectively only want some objects to respond to the stage size and others not, then that may not work. What you may have to do then is calculate the stage size differences and scale your objects accordingly.